# Issue connecting styles.scss in React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am having an issue with my React App connecting **style.scss** file. I think everything looks good to me on *webpack* a *package.json* but for some reason, it doesn't wanna works.

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./module.scss";

import Header from "../src/components/Header";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <Header />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Header.js:**

```
import React from "react";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="header">
        <div className="current-location">London</div>
        <div className="time">00:00 GMT</div>
        <div className="current-temp">23</div>
        <div className="reloading">Reloading</div>
        <div className="count-bar">seconds</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

**Webpack.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
  "@webpack-cli/serve": "^0.2.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
  "dotenv-webpack": "^1.8.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
  "promise": "^8.1.0",
  "react-html-id": "^0.1.5",
  "sass": "^1.26.5",
  "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
  "webpack": "^4.43.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "heroku": "^7.41.1",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
  "url-loader": "^4.1.0"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here? The Header is correctly rendered on App.js but I can't understand why style is not getting applied to. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,`?

Comment: Anything happened

Comment: webpack build is perfectly compiled without any error

Comment: only this one in the console :Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-… ("default-src").:

Comment: I have read some articles which says some browser extensions can cause this problem

Comment: Ok great, still not able to connect my css to App.js even after changing suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

replace

```
import './module.scss'
```

with

```
import style from './module.scss'
```

And use classes as variables like `className={style.time}` instead of `className="time"`

Comment: Still not working both.
Also getting this error in console: "Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-… ("default-src")."

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
},
{
  test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader',
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        // Run `postcss-loader` on each CSS `@import`, do not forget that `sass-loader` compile non CSS `@import`'s into a single file
        // If you need run `sass-loader` and `postcss-loader` on each CSS `@import` please set it to `2`
        importLoaders: 1,
        // Automatically enable css modules for files satisfying `/\.module\.\w+$/i` RegExp.
        modules: { auto: true },
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
    },
  ],
},
```

Reference: [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/)

Comment: Anything happened, build is correctly working but css is not responding at all.

Comment: this is my public repo
https://github.com/alessandrolepri/LocalForecast5